# How To Update State In Parent Component From Child Component In React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Current Code**

Parent.js

```js
export default class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nickname: 'parent'
    };
  }
}
```

Child.js

```js
export default class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nickname: props.navigation.state.params.nickname
    };
  }

  onPressUpdate() {
    const { nickname } = 'Child';
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Parent', { nickname: nickname });
  }
}
```

**What I'm Trying To Do**

Parent.js displays nickname and it is edited in Child.js.
Finishing to edit nickname, navigation goes back to Parent.js.
Then I wanna display a new nickname, 'Child' in above code.
I would appreciate it if you could give me any advices :)

Comment: Could you use http://snack.expo.io/ to share your react native code? That would be of great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) in parent code.

Something like this:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props.nickname !== prevProps.nickname ) {
    this.seteState({nickname:this.props.nickname});
  }
}
```

When you navigate from child to parent, pass the nickname to update, it will work and setState to new one.

Comment: Thanks. looks like componentDidUpdate is not working. Maybe navigation from child component to parent component is a problem?

Comment: Or maybe try change `this.props.nickname` to `this.props.navigation.state.params.nickname` like yours in if condition. I'm just take a example to explain.

Comment: Thanks. When navigating from child component to parent component, nothing happens. It doesn't trigger componentDidUpdate.

Comment: Or just change your parent view's state like children's `this.props.navigation.state.params.nickname || 'parent' ` without componentDidUpdate.

Comment: I think its about [navigationOptions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/#configuring-the-navigator) should add `nickname` as a props. If it doesn't work either, then I have no idea, sorry...